# How do I set a topMargin in my Anko layout

Tags: android, anko

I want my Anko layout to have a margin of 100dp on the top, so that the background of the app that gets defined in my theme file gets shown on the top.

I tried:

```
        verticalLayout {
            background = resources.getDrawable(R.color.white)

            textView("Headline")
            textView("App text...")

        }.lparams(topMargin = 100)
```

Unfortunately, the lparams gets marked red and when I however over it I get the error `unresolved reference: lparams`. How do I get my top margins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a `LinearLayout` inside of it as follows

```
verticalLayout {
    linearLayout {
        background = resources.getDrawable(R.color.white)

            textView("Headline")
            textView("App text...")
    }.lparams(width = matchParent, height = matchParent) {
      topMargin = dip(100)
    }
}
```

Also you can add a `lparams` inside of the `verticalLayout` as follows :

```
verticalLayout {
    ...
    lparams { ... }
}
```